# Styles.scss is not Being Applied Correctly Angular 8

Tags: angular, sass

I am using this [mondal/org-chart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mondal/org-chart) and running `angular 8.3.26`.  I have the data rendering but the sass styles are not applied.  It is supposed to look like this: [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mondal-org-chart?file=src%2Fstyles.scss)

I ran this command : `ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.styleext scss`and have added  `@import "~@mondal/org-chart/_theming.scss";` to the file styles.scss.

In the component I currently have:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'testOrg.component',
   templateUrl: './testOrg.component.html',       
})
```

What am I missing to get the correct styles applied?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add this code in your app.module.ts file? Import the OrgChart and add it into the 'imports' array.

```
import { OrgChartModule } from '@mondal/org-chart';
```